# Javascript Promise not populating list with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, promise

```js
app.get('/zones/:id/experiences', function(req,res) {
  var zone_key = req.params.id;
  var recent = [];
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('participants/'+zone_key+'/experiences');
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      promises.push(firebase.database().ref('experiences').child(snap.val()).once("value"));
      Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
        snapshots.forEach((usersnap) => {
          recent.push(usersnap.val()); //push objects into the "recent" list
        });
      });
    });
  });
  res.render('experiences',{key: zone_key, list: recent}); //render the view and pass the "recent" list to the client
});
```

In the above code, I query my Firebase DB to get a bunch of objects which I want to put into a list and then pass the list to my client view page. For some reason, I get the objects that I want from my DB but when I do that line "recent.push(usersnap.val())" the console log shows that I am adding the objects to the list but when I console log the "recent" list before the render, it comes up as empty. Is this a variable in/out of scope issue?

Comment: You can't render until `Promise.all` has resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render until `Promise.all` has resolved and you need to complete the loop before calling Promise.all(). Currently you are trying to process the whole promise array every iteration of the loop

Something like:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var promises = [];
  snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
    promises.push(firebase.database().ref('experiences').child(snap.val()).once("value"));    
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      snapshots.forEach((usersnap) => {
        recent.push(usersnap.val()); //push objects into the "recent" list
      });
      return recent
    })
    .then(recent => res.render('experiences', {key: zone_key,list: recent}))
    .catch(() => res.render( /* error display config*/ ))
});
```